# Environment variables in PyCharm not working

Tags: pycharm, environment-variables

Hello and sorry if this question has been solved before, i did, in my opinion, extensive research but can't find a solution anywhere.

I am a beginner learning Python, My problem is that environment variables defined in PyCharm's "Edit/Run Configuration" are not recognized, when i tried setting up the basic app with Flask with "hello.py" as the name of my Python file, the FLASK_APP environment variable is not being recognized.
I get the "Could not locate Flask app" error. PyCharm is running as admin and "echo %FLASK_APP%" just returns "%FLASK_APP%"

The venv is activated.

I've had this issue before when working with requests authentification but I just saved the keys in an actual variable, can't do this now.

I tried running the command set FLASK_APP=hello.py from the PyCharm terminal but same result.

When setting the environment variable manually from the Windows Environment Variables window, everything works perfectly but that means doing it everytime I start a new project and that doesn't seem like the proper way to do things.

I also tried all solutions provided by ChatGpt without result, and it seems like I can't find someone who had the same problem.

I can provide more details if needed, thanks in advance and sorry if it's a dumb-dumb question.

[image: Screenshot of the run config]

Comment: What does your run configuration look like?

Comment: I've added the screen to the post, sorry this is my first time here

Answer (score 0):

You can set your environment variables in Pycharm in Run -> Edit Configurations -> Environment -> Environment variables. Make sure to choose the python interpreter of your venv first.

Comment: Can you check the screenshot of the run configuration and tell me if I did something wrong ?

Comment: In the script path field you should put your flask executable which you should find in your venv, as parameter set "run"

Comment: This worked, but it works when i run my hello.py file, not when i use "flask run" from the terminal.
Does it have any impact when working on a project ?

Comment: You also have to activate your venv and set your environment variables in your terminal when you run it from there. Should not have an impact when you are working on your project